# calling php web service from an android client?

Tags: android, web-services

I'm very new to android programming and I tried to call a php web service from android using HttpClient. But while app is running it's stopped saying "Unfortunately ServiceTest is stopped" and terminated.
Following is my code.

```
public class ServiceTestActivity extends Activity {
private Button btn;
private TextView txt;
String result = ""; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            callWebErvice("http://localhost/mvc/login/test");

        }
    });

}

public void callWebErvice(String serviceURL) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serviceURL);  

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
        try {  
            result = httpclient.execute(request, handler); 
            txt.setText(result);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  

        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  

        }  
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  

        Log.i("my result", result);  
    } // end callWebServe
}
```

Can anybody find out the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of operations which we should never perform on UI thread.

1. Network operations.
2. DB operations
3. File operations.

From your code I can see that you are performing network operation on UI thread and it will definitely lead you into ANR (Application Not Responding).

Whenever ANR happens of application, android just kills the application.

You will have to use worker thread to perform Network Operation.